# CakePHP 2.x: Getting blank page when loading SoftDelete behavior

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, soft-delete, cakephp-2.x

I want to implement Soft Delete in my project. Could not find a reliable write-up over the same. The following is the only thing I got..

http://www.logicsart.com/cakephp/soft-delete-in-cakephp/

Anyway, I added respective columns in my database and
I tried to implement it by adding following code in my AppModel

```
public function exists($id = null) {
    if ($this->Behaviors->attached('SoftDelete')) {
    return $this->existsAndNotDeleted($id);
    } else {
    return parent::exists($id);
    }
}

public function delete($id = null, $cascade = true) {
    $result = parent::delete($id, $cascade);
    if ($result === false && $this->Behaviors->enabled('SoftDelete')) {
    return $this->field('deleted', array('deleted' => 1));
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Following, in my `bootstrap.php`

```
CakePlugin::loadAll();
```

And following in my model,

```
public $actsAs = array('SoftDelete');
```

I have also included `SoftDeleteBehavior.php` in app/Model/Behavour folder.

The problem I am facing is, when I include $actsAs in my Model, the page doesn`t display any data, and if I exclude it, the Soft delete wont work.
If you have a more concrete source to implement Soft delete, that would help as well, Any help will be appreciated.Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check the typo in your behavior folder. You've written

```
/app/Model/Behavour
```

when it should be

```
/app/Model/Behavior
```

Next, the version of `SoftDelete` you are using is probably outdated, and may have bugs which have been fixed in recent versions.

You should install `CakeDC/utils` with composer:

```
"require": {
    "cakedc/utils": "master"
}
```

`CakePlugin::loadAll()` is needed when you choose to install as a Plugin, but not so if you download the individual class into `app/Model/Behavior` folder.

Also, don't forget to create the two fields in your database table: `deleted` `TINYINT(1)` and `deleted_date` `DATETIME`.

Remember to have debug enabled on your development server by setting

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);
```

in `app/Config/core.php`.